# Amazon Linux, PHP 5.5: php.ini ignored

Tags: php, yum, php.ini, apache-2.4, amazon-linux

On our Amazon EC2 instance, I uninstalled PHP5.3 (`yum remove php`) and installed PHP 5.5, which also bundled in Apache 2.4 (`yum install php54`).

For some reason, my `php.ini` file is no longer being read. It looks like it may be deprecated, and maybe I should use `/etc/php-5.5.ini` instead - but that one isn't being read either! (Strangely, I can't find any documentation on this. Googling "php-5.5.ini" (with quotes) returns no helpful results!??)

Running `php --ini`, I get this:

```
[ec2-user@ip ~]$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php-5.5.d
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php-5.5.d/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php-5.5.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php-5.5.d/apc.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/bz2.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/calendar.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/ctype.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/curl.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/dom.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/exif.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/ftp.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/gd.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/gettext.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/iconv.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/json.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/mbstring.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/mysqlnd.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/mysqlnd_mysql.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/mysqlnd_mysqli.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/pdo.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/pdo_mysqlnd.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/phar.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/php.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/posix.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/shmop.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/simplexml.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/sockets.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/sqlite3.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/tokenizer.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/xml.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/xml_wddx.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/xsl.ini,
/etc/php-5.5.d/zip.ini
```

Neither ini file are listed here. There's a `/etc/php-5.5.d/php.ini`, but it is blank except for this message: `; The php.ini file has moved to /etc/php-5.5.ini.`

But again, /etc/php-5.5.ini isn't being read either...

I'm not sure what the ".d" naming scheme means here - is it "default" or "daemon" or something else?

What can I do to get either of these INI files read? Or do I just need to throw everything into `/etc/php-5.5.d/php.ini`?

Comment: This helped me http://superuser.com/a/438060/370857

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP is configured to read all `.ini` files in the `/etc/php-5.5.d` folder. This allows for logical separation of settings - APC's settings go into `apc.ini`, memcached's go in `memcached.ini`, etc.

You can put any settings you want to modify in `/etc/php-5.5.d/php.ini` or create a new `.ini` in the folder. `/etc/php-5.5.d/DOOManiac.ini` would work just fine, for example.

Regarding `.d` folders:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4029/what-does-the-d-stand-for-in-directory-names

Comment: That's what it looks like, except for the fact that `/etc/php-5.5.d/php.ini` is devoid of any 'default' settings and merely points the user to `/etc/php-5.5.ini`. I know it would work, but it feels kind of hacky, so I just wanted to check and make sure that yes this is what I should really do. Thanks

Comment: Also, thanks for clarifying the `.d` issue!

Comment: An empty `php.ini` file will still get PHP's internal defaults. Some distributions pre-populate the default `php.ini` file with a big long list of default settings, but it's not strictly necessary. You can run PHP with no `php.ini` file whatsoever, in fact.

Comment: Okay, I bit the bullet and did `sudo cp /etc/php-5.5.ini /etc/php-5.5.d/php.ini`. Everything works fine now. I guess I'll just delete all these old INI files and tell everyone it's in a different place now...

Comment: Other option - symlink `/etc/php-5.5.ini` to `/etc/php-5.5.d/php.ini` or the other way around.

Comment: Would've worked, but I get confused easily and would just prefer to have it in one place. :)

Comment: If i symlink it, is that going to get erased/overwritten when I upgrade PHP with yum?